# AS3 Blitting - Copy Pixels getting some of the source image

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, bitmapdata

I am trying to draw something on the screen and then, copy that onto a bitmap which is on stage.

I have done this before, with a procedurally drawn shape like a circle but when I use a library item most of the source pixels get cut off.

here's my code - in another function the bitmap object is added to the stage and I can see that copyPixels work but as I have said copies only some of the pixels. I have tried playing with the Rectangle but no luck so far.

```
var s:StarAsset = new StarAsset();

        s.x = e.stageX;
        s.y = e.stageY;
        s.scaleX = e.pressure * 10;
        s.scaleY = e.pressure * 10;
        s.rotation = Math.random() * 360;



        var bms:BitmapData = new BitmapData(s.width + 6, s.height + 6, true, 0x00000000);
        bms.draw(s);

        var srect:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
        srect.width = s.width + 6;
        srect.height = s.height + 6;

        var destpoint:Point = new Point(s.x, s.y);
        bmcontainer.copyPixels(bms, srect, destpoint, null, null, true);
```

Answer (score 7):

Using a star asset:

[image: star-asset]

And assuming your are blitting to a canvas bitmap on the stage:

```
var canvas:BitmapData = new BitmapData(600, 600, true, 0x0);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(canvas, PixelSnapping.AUTO, true);
addChild(bitmap);
```

This implementation would instantiate your `StarAsset`, draw it to `BitmapData`, and then randomly transform scale, position, and rotation per copy drawn to the canvas:

```
makeStars();

function makeStars():void
{
    // get the star asset
    var s:StarAsset = new StarAsset();

    // copy star asset to bitmap data
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(s.width, s.height, true, 0x0);
    bd.draw(s);

    // draw 100 variants on BitmapData
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var positionX:Number = Math.random() * 600;
        var positionY:Number = Math.random() * 600;
        var scale:Number = Math.random();
        var angle:Number = Math.random() * 360;

        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.scale(scale, scale);
        matrix.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
        matrix.translate(positionX, positionY);

        canvas.draw(bd, matrix, null, null, null, true);
    }
}
```

Which produces:

[image: stars]

Or here 1,000 stars are drawn:

[image: stars-1000]

Or finally 10,000 stars are drawn:

[image: stars-10000]

Comment: Holy cow, you are one helpful guy! I have not used matrices and will try when I am done with my work today. Thank you so very much Jason.